# Integrating prometheus jmx_exporter with jboss application

Tags: jboss, prometheus, jmx, jmx-exporter, prometheus-java

I am very new to the jboss application and trying to integrate prometheus jmx_exporter with jboss-EAP 7.0.0 on windows. I am trying to run in domain configuration mode. Below are the changes that I have did in host.xml

```
 <jvm-options>
            <option value="-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\jboss-eap-7.0\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\logmanager\main\jboss-logmanager-2.0.3.Final-redhat-1.jar"/>
            <option value="-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"/> 
            <option value="-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"/>
            <option value="-javaagent:C:\jboss-eap-7.0\bin\jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar=58080:C:\jboss-eap-7.0\domain\configuration\config.yml"/>
 </jvm-options>
```

getting the logs as below

```
[Server:server-one] WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
[Server:server-one] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.logmanager.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:57)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.as.server.DomainServerMain.main(DomainServerMain.java:92)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Server:server-one]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Server:server-one]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:329)
[Server:server-one]     at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:507)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you need to update the system-properties, for example in domain.xml:

```
    </extensions>
      <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.manager" value="org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"/>
        <property name="jboss.modules.system.pkgs" value="org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"/>
      </system-properties>
    <management>
```